# Name of this graph transformation?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let's say I have a task dependency graph (directed, acyclic), where each node is a task and each directed edge represent a dependency relationship between two nodes. For example, $A \to B \to C$ would mean that task $A$ must be completed first, and then task $B$, and then task $C$.

We can take advantage of concurrent tasks in this task graph. If our graph is $A \to B$, $A \to C$, then we must finish task $A$ first, and then $B$ and $C$ can be executed concurrently.

To simplify the graph, for every chain of nodes that cannot be executed concurrently, I want to be able to combine that chain of nodes into one big task. $A \to B \to C$ would become A_then_B_then_C; three nodes would be collapsed into one. If my task graph were $A \to B$, $A \to C$, then I would not collapse these nodes together, because I want to be able to run $B$ and $C$ concurrently, which wouldn't be possible if I grouped it together with $A$.

Some diagrams to illustrate this transformation:

[image]

Before Transformation

[image]

After Transformation

Note that $F$, $G$, and $H$ were collapsed into one node as well, so this algorithm isn't quite the same as a radix trie.

Collapsing linear nodes seems like a pretty useful transformation that has definitely been studied before. I can't seem to find the name for it though, can anyone help?

Comment: Not quite what you are asking for, but [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) seems relevant.

Comment: In terms of how it constrains the order of execution, the edge from $F$ to $H$ in the original graph is redundant, so maybe you want a rule that lets you eliminate that edge before you apply edge contraction, in order to keep the rule for edge contraction simple. What do you want to do if your original graph has edges $(P,Q),$ $(Q,R),$ $(R,S),$ $(P,R),$ and $(Q,S)$? Presumably you want to contract these to P_then_Q_then_R_then_S if there are no other edges in or out of $Q$ or $R.$

Comment: @angryavian Yes, this is quite close. I guess what I'm looking for is a name/algorithm for edge contraction of linear nodes in directed acyclic graphs. I was curious if it was already out there.

Comment: @DavidK I believe a transitive reduction is what you're looking for to simplify your example.

Comment: My example is just a more complicated example of what you have going on with F, G, and H. What I'm suggesting is to apply the transitive reduction there before trying to combine the three nodes. I think there will be other cases that distinguish what you're doing from a radix trie, but they're a little more complicated to describe.